# C Replace Printed Text

Tags: c

So I have this script and I want to replace printed "Dont" with "Lets". I don't want to use system() since the effect is different.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("Dont do this");
    /* Replace printed "Dont" with "Lets" */
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: `printf("Lets do this");`? It's not clear what you want/need to change as that string is hard coded into the `printf`.

Comment: I suspect you're looking for something like `printf("Dont do this\n"); sleep(3);  printf("\033[ALets\n");`.  On ANSI-compatible terminals and terminal emulators, at least, `ESC [ A` moves the cursor up one line.

Comment: I wanted to replace "Dont" without deleting "do this"

Comment: On my screen, that's exactly what happens.  If yours isn't working that way, you might try `printf("\033[ALets");` or `printf("\033[ALets\033[B\n");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `\r`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("Dont do this");
    printf("\rLets");
    printf("\n");
    return 0; 
}
```